# layout for large and xlarge screens not taking effect on my project

Tags: android, layout, size, screen

i'm trying to adjust my layout for phones and Tablets ( large and Xlarge ) , i'm using the layout's best practice config as explained in http://developer.android.com (res/layout-large/my_layout.xml and res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml ) but when i'm testing it on my different virtual devices i see no effect for large and xlarge tablets ( text looks small ) even if i'm using bigger size for large and xlarge layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `large` and `xlarge` qualifiers isn't recommended any more -- you should use the smallest-width qualifier instead. For 7" tablets, you can use `sw600dp`, and for 10" you can use `sw720dp`.

Comment: does it work for all android version ? i think ur solution is working for 3.1 and up.

Comment: You just have to target honeycomb and up. You can still support earlier versions, but essentially all tablets are running 3.1 are higher.

Comment: i used honeycomb as target , 10.1in WXGA (Tablet) as virtual device and two layer fodlers as you said but it's still not working , i wonder what's wrong.